# How to use an InputBox with a table - Domino Designer

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

I would like to create a button which then opens an inputbox, the user then inputs a message, and then I would like to create a table with there name & the message in, on the same form.

Is this possible in Domino Designer?
Formula?
LotusScripts?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. It's not trivial. What have you tried?

Comment: does it have to be a table? an embedded view would be simpler

Comment: You need a rich text field to do this. Take a look at the NotesRichText class in Lotusscript, this allow you to create any kind of rich text formatting to your documents

Comment: follow-up on Nick Gilbert's comment:

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the proper use case, and expecting that more than just one user will be able to click that button for a single document, let me recommend a slightly different solution:

I tend to solve these by using a simple multi value text field, make it computed when composed. Then if a user enters a message I append (or prepend) a new line to the list field like in

[Lothar Mueller, 2015-05-01 15:00:01]: this is my message